# How can I modify a Linux USB block driver?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, block, usb-drive

I am working on a project where I need to add some of my own modifications to a Linux UBS Block device driver. I need access to the driver's source code, change it and I need to be able to run and test it with real USB thumb drives.

The problem is, I'm not sure where to begin. So I have three general questions:

1) Where can I get a Linux USB block device driver such that I can compile the source code myself?

2) How can I then run this driver and use it with a real thumb drive?

Any other tips for this project would surely be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/) (and years of doing this myself)

```
cd linux-src
make menuconfig
make
make install
reboot now
```

Also [here](http://m.linuxjournal.com/article/8093) is a more in depth article about how USB support in the Linux Kernal is designed.